# How can a Raku UDP server know where to send a response to?

Tags: sockets, udp, raku

I can write a UDP server that will receive messages from a client using IO::Socket::Async

```
my $socket = IO::Socket::Async.bind-udp: 'localhost', 3333;

react whenever $socket.Supply: :bin {
    say "Received some junk: { .gist }";    
}
```

And I can send things to this server:

```
given IO::Socket::Async.udp {
    await .print-to: 'localhost', 3333, 'Hello';
}
```

But when I try to get the server to send back a message response, I realise I don't have the host and port to send it to. How can I get this information?

Normally, I think the answer to this would be to use `recvfrom` and pass a pointer to a `sockaddr` struct that will get populated with the address information of the incoming connection. But there seems to be no way to do this without reaching for NativeCall (and even then it's not clear to me how to do that).

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** The solution to your problem was implemented by timo++ in response to a similar SO question to yours and then nicely documented by Kaiepi  in [their accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048147/1077672). Please visit and upvote there accordingly. The rest of what I write here is arguably redundant.

---

The official doc doesn't mention the solution (passing a `:datagram` argument to the `IO::Socket::Async.Supply` method) and using the [`Datagram`s](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/b340c2b185842ef13c49581bd055dbf623412d64/src/core.c/IO/Socket/Async.pm6#L47-L62) you then get from the supply.

Here's an example of it using low level taps of supplies at both ends:

```
# Server

given IO::Socket::Async .bind-udp('localhost', 3333) {
  .Supply(:datagram)
    .tap: {
      say "Received client data: { .data.gist }";
      IO::Socket::Async.udp.print-to: .hostname, .port, 'Loud and clear!';
    }
}

# Client

given IO::Socket::Async.udp {
  .print-to: 'localhost', 3333, 'Can you hear me?';
  .Supply
    .tap: {
      say "Received server data: { .gist }";
      IO::Socket::Async.udp.print-to: 'localhost', 3333, 'Great :)';
    }
}

sleep 1;
```

displays:

```
Received client data: Can you hear me?
Received server data: Hi!
Received client data: Great :)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very useful. I am surprised to hear that this has spent 5 years merged and yet remains undocumented. Is that just a lack of TUITs? Or are there parts of this that are still a draft? Also: is there a reason you create a new socket to write to the client, rather than just `$socket.print-to`? I noticed that the way you do it, the client gets a response coming from a different port than the one it connected to, which seems like it would be unexpected, but maybe there's a good reason to do that?

Comment: @jja I don't understand socket programming. I just took your Q as a challenge, as I do with any Q if I have time. So I read doc, code, and issues, and googled, and tried code. I eventually wrote a comment on your question asking if the older SO was the answer, because it seemed like it was. Then I kept going to see if I could get a result that convinced me it was indeed the answer. I got as far as the above, late at night, and decided to delete my tentative comment and replace it with this answer. But I was confused about the client response. I'm currently trying to understand what you mean...

Comment: Ha! No problem. I had not seen that other question, so I'm glad you took the time to help. And I'm glad to know there's no special reason to do it that way: it'll keep the cargo-culting to a minimum

Comment: @jja "new socket ... rather than just `$socket.print-to` ... response coming from a different port than the one it connected to ... maybe there's a good reason to do that?" No, as explained in my above comment. I'd love to fix the code or file a Rakudo and/or doc issue if you and/or I can figure out what's missing in my code or Rakudo or the doc.

Comment: @jja "I am surprised to hear that this has spent 5 years merged and yet remains undocumented. Is that just a lack of TUITs? Or are there parts of this that are still a draft?" I was surprised too. It's the reason I mentioned the time span. I haven't investigated what's going on but at a guess it's both conceptual draft status (there's no mention of 'datagram' in [roast's `IO-Socket-Async.t`](https://github.com/Raku/roast/blob/dffc2a4cec4a1b91a14289a88cead3ceecd5f5b4/S32-io/IO-Socket-Async.t)) and lack of tuits all round (in overall Raku project coordination prioritization, and documentation).

Comment: Please make a documentation issue!  Or even better, a documentation PR!